# Idiomatic way of tracing an object through your system with `tracing`?

Tags: rust, trace, rust-tokio, rust-tracing

Context: event-driven system where objects go through a bunch of subsystems (Tokio architecture, communication over channels). I want to have spans that track the object through the system, from start to finish. Is the idiomatic way to do this just attaching a span to the object and entering / exiting it each time it arrives at a different subsystem?

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly reasonable thing to do. The alternative would be to attach some event identifier to each span that handles it with throughout the system and filter by it in your trace-viewing tool of choice.